# Windows 2012 R2 server, crash, no dump file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, server-crashes

I have a Windows 2012 R2 dedicated server. 64 GB RAM. Sitting in a remote datacenter.

It crashes about 1-2 times a day. I have a KVM over the internet that I can view the screen. Screen says Critical_Process_Died. Says it is collecting information and gets stuck at 0%.

I never get a dump file.

I have configured a small memory dump and set the Page File to be system recommended at 12GB. Played around with these settings with no luck.

Nothing in the event viewer indicates any kind of system problem or is very helpful related to this crash. I have a bunch of custom applications on the server as well as a couple of services. Nothing in the event viewer about any problems with these. Server runs fine until it freezes and crashes.

I have upgraded the RAID card drivers and have run CPU, Memory and Hard Drive diagnostics. No errors. Nothing in the RAID logs indicating any problems.

I am trying to find other options to troubleshoot this issue and to point me in the right direction.

Please let me know if there is any other information that I can provide that might better pinpoint the problem.

Update:  Machine Specs

Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit

CPU: Intel Xeon E5 1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz    27 °C
Ivy Bridge-EP/EX 22nm Technology

RAM: 64.0GB DDR3 @ 799MHz (11-11-11-28)

Motherboard:Supermicro X9SRE/X9SRE-3F/X9SRi/X9SRi-3F (SOCKET 0) 60 °C

Graphics:
    Generic Non-PnP Monitor (1280x1024@64Hz)
    Matrox Microsoft Basic Display Adapter (Super Micro Computer)

Storage:1116GB LSI MR9271-4i SCSI Disk Device (RAID)

Comment: Try this - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: No dump file is created, so this will not work.  I can analyze dump files as I do it all the time with the debugger.  Just baffled as to why no dump file is created.

Comment: What make/model of hardware?

Comment: If you force a blue screen crash, does that generate a dump file?

Comment: I have been trying to force a crash with the ctrl-scroll lock(2) method.  I change the registry settings and followed the instructions.  However I do not have physical access to the keyboard.  Only remote KVM and Teamviewer.  Sending the commands through either does not crash the system.

Comment: Sysinternals have a tool for forcing a blue screen crash: https://download.sysinternals.com/files/notmyfault.zip

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the pagefile is big enough configured an if there is enough diskspace to create the full pagefile and dumpfile, if the pagefile is to small configured or there is not enough diskspace, then windows will not create a dump file.

Comment: I played around with the Page File and its size.  Nothing helped.  Nothing in event viewer either.  I had small memory dump enabled so not sure the page file size mattered here.  I had it set to system managed for most of the time and still no dump file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being the RAID card.  The company that hosts the server replaced the card and I have not had a crash since.

Thanks for all of the comments and help.